# Web SQL transaction does not execute properly in javascript function

Tags: javascript, sql, function, web-sql

I have JavaScript function that returns array of selected values from my local database.

```
var dataBase = {
  select : selectFunction
}

var db = openDatabase(..);

var data=[ ];
function selectFunction() {
    db.transaction(function (t) {
     t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Table", [], function (t, results) {
       for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            data.push(results.rows.item(i));
        }
     });
   });
  return data;//return "stackoverflow" //works fine
}
```

I want to do something like this

```
var getSelect = dataBase.select();
alert(getSelect);
```

If I return string like "stackoverflow", this will work fine

```
 alert result: stackoverflow
```

But if I try to return the 'data', the function returns undefined

I noticed that  `db.transaction` is executing after the return statement, and I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When returning results from an asynchronous function, you must use a callback, as the function will return before the actual operation has completed. You can rewrite your function like so:

```
function selectFunction(callback) {
    db.transaction(function (t) {
     t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Table", [], function (t, results) {
       for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            data.push(results.rows.item(i));
        }
        callback(data);
     });
   });
}
```

And then call it, passing a callback:

```
dataBase.select(function(data){
    var getSelect = data
    alert(getSelect);
});
```